# Query data from two tables does not work, query only a single tables works

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Here is my export.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1` (
  `order_id` int(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `order_date` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tkt_order_id` int(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_date` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_name` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_year` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mail` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ticket_type` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ticket_days` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ticket_subtype` varchar(18) DEFAULT NULL,
  `base` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `service` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gross` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `order_id` (`order_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `email` (`mail`,`order_date`,`event_name`,`event_year`,`quantity`,`ticket_type`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table2` (
  `mail` varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `first_name` varchar(27) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(63) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address2` varchar(38) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(27) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(22) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`mail`),
  UNIQUE KEY `mail` (`mail`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `index` (`first_name`,`lastname`,`city`,`state`,`zip`,`country`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



ALTER TABLE `table1`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `table1_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`mail`) REFERENCES `table2` (`mail`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Comment: Where is the query which works not as expected?

Comment: both the sales table and the failing query (and the error from there/result from there) is missing

Comment: His issue is repeating rows, no errors according to the post. Maybe try to SELECT DISTINCT to ignore duplicate rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include the meaningful link on the foreign key in your where-clause:

```
db.sales.mail = db.customers.mail
```

Also, use brackets to group your conditions together. Something like `cond1 OR cond2 AND cond3` will probably not work as expected, so for example you could write this as `(cond1 OR cond2) AND cond3`.

So something like this should work:

```
SELECT db.customers.first_name, 
 db.customers.last_name, 
 db.customers.mail, 
 db.sales.event_year, 
 db.sales.ticket_type, 
 db.sales.event_name
FROM db.sales, db.customers
WHERE db.sales.mail = db.customer.mail
AND (db.sales.ticket_type = "ticket1" 
OR db.sales.ticket_type = "ticket2" 
OR db.sales.ticket_type = "ticket3")
AND (db.sales.event_year=2009 
OR db.sales.event_year=2010)
```

While the above should work, it's better to write it like this (mostly for readability):

```
SELECT c.first_name, 
 c.last_name, 
 c.mail, 
 s.event_year, 
 s.ticket_type, 
 s.event_name
FROM db.sales s
INNER JOIN db.customer c ON s.mail = c.mail
WHERE s.ticket_type IN ('ticket1','ticket2','ticket3')
AND s.event_year IN (2009,2010);
```

Note: I simply removed the final `GROUP BY` in your query, since I don't know what you're trying to accomplish with that. If you use `GROUP BY`, it should be on at least all selected columns that are not aggregate functions (like `SUM`, `COUNT` etc.)

Answer (score -1):

Use left join instead of inner join. Eg:

```
SELECT c.*, s.*
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN sales s ON s.email = c.email;
```

Comment: There is no reason to use a `LEFT JOIN`. Both the mail columns cannot be null

Comment: When I answered that there was no create table code. But you are correct.